# Can't insert column into a newly created dataframe (Python - Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

Let **df** be a dataframe. I'm trying to place the column **a** into another dataframe called **df2**

```
 df2.insert(1,'a',df['a'])
```

Everything goes well when df2 is loaded from excel:

```
df2 = pandas.read_excel(filepath)
```

Yet, when I create df2 from scratch, there's an error:

```
df2 = pandas.DataFrame
```

The error reads:

```
insert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
```

What is going on?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame` is a class, you want to create an instance of that so do `df2 = pd.DataFrame()` so that `df2` is a DataFrame object. Also counting starts at 0, so you'll need to `insert(0, 'a' ,df['a'])`

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is that you give a value in `pd.DataFrame(abc)` 
now here `abc` can be a matrix or dictionary

you can use this too:

`pd.DataFrame(df[['a']])`

Comment: I'm starting df2 from scratch. Only columns from df1 should be placed there.

Comment: i hope now it helps